# How to manually sync Mesibo Phone Contacts

Tags: android, kotlin, mesibo

I want to create manual contact sync button like whatsapp, I use Mesibo.getPhoneContactsManager().start() from sample code, how to check sync status, is in process, failed or done, and how to get the latest synced contact list ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to the documentation here

https://docs.mesibo.com/api/phone-contacts-and-addressbook/monitoring-and-synchronization/

You can implement a listener which can give you status as it syncs

```
boolean Mesibo_onPhoneContactsAdded(String[] phoneNumbers){


    return true;
}
```

If you prefer to syncronize manually, refer to the syncronization documetation here

https://docs.mesibo.com/api/users-and-profiles/contact-management-and-profile-synchronization/

For example, use code below is iOS to synchronize following contacts manually.

```
String[] contacts = {"18005550001", "18005550002", "18005550003"};

MesiboContactSynchronizer *syncer = new MesiboContactSynchronizer();
syncer.subscribe(true);
syncer.setProfileAccessLevels([1,2,5]);
syncer.sync(contacts, true);
```